# Android: tabs within tabs

Tags: android, android-layout, tabs

I'm currently trying to create an application according the customer's specs, and these include a double tab set.

Meaning that the user needs to click in a tab at the bottom, and for example in the first tab, he will also see a set of tabs at the top where he can click (but when clicking in these, only the ones at the top will change, while the tabs at the bottom will remain the same).

How could I perform this with Android?
So far I could only implement the normal tabs creating a root item 'TabHost' just like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<TabHost xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@android:id/tabhost"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" >

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <FrameLayout
            android:id="@android:id/tabcontent"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true" >
        </FrameLayout>

        <TabWidget
            android:id="@android:id/tabs"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true" />
    </RelativeLayout>

</TabHost>
```

Thanks a lot in advance!

Comment: Why can't you have tabhost in your activity's layout file,which is to be loaded when tab-1 would be selecteD?make activity_1 as tab activity and you will find your second tabhost working.

Comment: @Hiral sorry but I didn't understand your answer. What should I do?

Comment: When you click on one of the tab,you start an activity,right?in that activity,you will have a layout file.I told you to have tabhost there too,so that when you will load acitivty,it will give you tabs inside a tab.

Comment: @Hiral would it be simpler to create Fragments for all this?

Comment: sorry,i have not worked with fragments yet!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found this, thanks to the ActionBar (and SherlockActionBar for pre-Honeycomb devices):

http://developer.android.com/resources/samples/ApiDemos/src/com/example/android/apis/app/ActionBarTabs.html

and also this:

http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=gMu8XhxUBl8